# How to open the specifc PDF page with Xamarin (iOS)?

Tags: c#, ios, pdf, xamarin

I use the following code to open a PDF document. I would like to know how to open the PDF on a specific page, because every time I run the code the document opens at the beginning.

```
 public void OpenFile(string targetPath)
    {
        try
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                QLPreviewItemFileSystem prevItem = new QLPreviewItemFileSystem(_name, targetPath);
                QLPreviewController previewController = new QLPreviewController();
                previewController.DataSource = new PreviewControllerDS(prevItem);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(previewController, true, null);
            });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Different from word or txt , it is a complete document, which may be converted from other type of document. You can use Quartz to .inspect PDF file structure.Refer to the link https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-CJBDCGCB